# Problem using jQuery > selector

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have something like the following jQuery code

```
buttons =
document.createElement('div');      
$(buttons).addClass("overlay_buttons").css({
           styles });

save =
document.createElement('input');
$(save).attr({  type: "button",
    value: "Save" 
}).css({width:'45%'});

undo =
document.createElement('input');
$(undo).attr({  type: "button",
    value: "Start again" 
}).css({width:'93%'});

//add elements to document
$(buttons).append(undo);
$(buttons).append(save); 
$(buttons +'> input').css({
       shared styles for buttons 
});
```

The problem I have is that the shared styles for the buttons don't apply. I get no error messages. I've also tried using other jQuery methods to check it's not the css that's the problem, but nothing applied to $(buttons +'> input') works.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$(buttons +'> input').css({
   shared styles for buttons 
});
```

`buttons` at that point is not a string, but a DOM element object. So when you try to append this object to the string `> input` your selector ends up being something like "[object HTMLDivElement] > input", which is obviously not right.

This *should* work, as according to the [`children()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children#expr) documentation it only selects the immediate children, replicating the behavior of the `>` selector:

```
$(buttons).children('input').css({
   shared styles for buttons 
});
```

Or, if that doesn't, which it should, then you can try this, although I don't feel good about it:

```
$('> input', buttons).css({
   shared styles for buttons 
});
```

Also, I am not sure why you are individually creating the elements with `createElement`. jQuery supports creating DOM elements [on the fly](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#htmlownerDocument). Using that, you can shorten this:

```
undo =
document.createElement('input');
$(undo).attr({  type: "button",
    value: "Start again" 
}).css({width:'93%'});
```

To this:

```
$('<input>').attr({  type: "button",
    value: "Start again" 
}).css({width:'93%'});
```